# RSA Encryption in C# PEM format

Tags: c#, asp.net, rsa, bouncycastle

I have a method in C# that I pass a public key string.

```cs
public string RsaEncryptWithPublic(string clearText, string publicKey)

    {
      byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clearText);
      Pkcs1Encoding pkcs1Encoding = new Pkcs1Encoding((IAsymmetricBlockCipher) new RsaEngine());
      using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(publicKey))
      {
        AsymmetricKeyParameter parameters = (AsymmetricKeyParameter) new PemReader((TextReader) reader).ReadObject();
        pkcs1Encoding.Init(true, (ICipherParameters) parameters);
      }
      return Convert.ToBase64String(pkcs1Encoding.ProcessBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));
    }
```

The public key string that I pass is

```cs
string publicKey = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAlUCQZso6P43gKqw0CfTlwYb3N+m4v6IME 4nPA3WXe52wFpDM/JCFWSdXa7BewlwzDYjblgwL4u59CPxNTPTh7LTD4xXOaGDJHjX5+YgqK4fb9rs ImjMpIACrND/LAdrq5mctWWzw3UtW3F+o+sNwIZM8n65ysS+Vhq9IypFlfuQbWrKjAcWZ3u1iLtplz yf/pjhOEyyZiBUnh6D219+pMiE9nhCpc4xkH1gnlGszIDBqZMMULtGJvFXydA1vv5HxxCYJ2ydEzmA KYxVgA9BGXPEGE89dQbeJsieTj+FSsp9oTm+4vi345opRvH8DWhmZc4OPSwBEL8pwgS7cUnKPtwIDA QAB";
```

I get an error Org.BouncyCastle.Security.InvalidKeyException: 'Not an RSA key'.  Is the publickey format that I passed to the method is incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted key is an RSA key in X.509/SPKI format. `PemReader` expects a PEM encoded key. However, the posted key is not PEM encoded, it is missing header, footer and line breaks after every 64 characters. The PEM encoded key looks like this:

```cs
string publicKey = @"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAlUCQZso6P43gKqw0CfTl
wYb3N+m4v6IME4nPA3WXe52wFpDM/JCFWSdXa7BewlwzDYjblgwL4u59CPxNTPTh
7LTD4xXOaGDJHjX5+YgqK4fb9rsImjMpIACrND/LAdrq5mctWWzw3UtW3F+o+sNw
IZM8n65ysS+Vhq9IypFlfuQbWrKjAcWZ3u1iLtplzyf/pjhOEyyZiBUnh6D219+p
MiE9nhCpc4xkH1gnlGszIDBqZMMULtGJvFXydA1vv5HxxCYJ2ydEzmAKYxVgA9BG
XPEGE89dQbeJsieTj+FSsp9oTm+4vi345opRvH8DWhmZc4OPSwBEL8pwgS7cUnKP
twIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
```

Regarding line breaks `PemReader` is tolerant: Only header and footer must be in separate lines.

Btw, as of .NET Core 3.0, import of a DER encoded RSA key in X.509/SPKI format is supported by [`RSA.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importsubjectpublickeyinfo?view=net-6.0). As of .NET 5, import of PEM encoded RSA keys is supported with [`RSA.ImportFromPem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importfrompem?view=net-6.0).

Comment: How can I test if the encryption is correct?  I have copied your code and it keeps on producing different strings after every execution ( ecncryption)

Comment: @ddb20 - Encryption with RSA is *not* deterministic, i.e. each encryption produces a different ciphertext (so this is not a bug). The correctness of the encryption can be proven by decryption with the private key associated with the public key used for encryption.