# RSA Encryption string public key to RSA Public Key

Tags: java, c#, rsa, public-key-encryption

The given public key to me is in this string format

```
string publicKey =
"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAlUCQZso6P43gKqw0CfTlwYb3N+m4v6IME 4nPA3WXe52wFpDM/JCFWSdXa7BewlwzDYjblgwL4u59CPxNTPTh7LTD4xXOaGDJHjX5+YgqK4fb9rs ImjMpIACrND/LAdrq5mctWWzw3UtW3F+o+sNwIZM8n65ysS+Vhq9IypFlfuQbWrKjAcWZ3u1iLtplz yf/pjhOEyyZiBUnh6D219+pMiE9nhCpc4xkH1gnlGszIDBqZMMULtGJvFXydA1vv5HxxCYJ2ydEzmA KYxVgA9BGXPEGE89dQbeJsieTj+FSsp9oTm+4vi345opRvH8DWhmZc4OPSwBEL8pwgS7cUnKPtwIDA QAB";
```

One line in the sample code in java that the public key needs to be converted to RSA Public key.
Does the lines below converts a string public key to RSAPublicKey?  Is there a counterpart in C#?

```
byte[] decoedPublicKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKey);
RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").
    generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(decoedPublicKey));
```

I am trying to send an RSA encrypted message to an external API and always the api returns an error that it could not decrypt the message.  I am not doing this step in my c# app, is this required in correct RSA encryption of the public key.  Below is a snippet of my RSA encryption. Is it correct?

```
 Pkcs1Encoding pkcs1Encoding = new Pkcs1Encoding((IAsymmetricBlockCipher)new RsaEngine());
            using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(publicKey))
            {
                AsymmetricKeyParameter parameters = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)new PemReader((TextReader)reader).ReadObject();
                pkcs1Encoding.Init(true, (ICipherParameters)parameters);
            }

            return Convert.ToBase64String(pkcs1Encoding.ProcessBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));
```

Comment: A first step is to simply run the code and see what happens. So, what happens when you run it?

Comment: You have asked the same question here: [RSA Encryption in C# PEM format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72538797/rsa-encryption-in-c-sharp-pem-format). And the answer is the same.

Comment: Decryption can also fail for other reasons, e.g. private and public key are not related, the padding is not correct,...

Comment: I note that the encoded key contains spaces. Base64 decoding fails for me unless I remove them